# Как вычислить градус поворота между точками?

Tags: javascript, математика, геометрия

Есть две точки на карте точка  ***a*** = (55.7526, 37.57) и ***b*** = (55.7576, 37.58)

Объект находящийся на точке ***а*** должен иметь угол разворота чтобы смотреть на точку **b**. Т.е. имея эти точки нужно вычислить градус поворота.

Comment: Как точка может смотреть? Какой стороной смотрит точка?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Объект находится на точке. Нужно вычислить угол поворота объекта, чтобы он развернулся в сторону точки **b**

Comment: Для этого надо знать, объект куда смотрит. Тут скорее не точка нужна, а вектор. Ну или прямая.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Куда бы не смотрел объект к нему нужно применить градусы чтобы он повернулся на **b**

Comment: @Igor очень смешно) В таком случае, поверните точку на 0 градусов. И тогда точка будет смотреть на объект. Что бы это не значило...

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы получить угол в полном диапазоне, можно использовать

```
  an =  Math.atan2(b.y-a.y, b.x-a.x)
```

В большинстве языков результат будет в радианах, при необходимости его можно  перевести в градусы

```
deg_an = an * 180 / Math.Pi 
// или функциями вроде toDegrees, RadToDeg
```

Добавлю, что если эти точки представляют географические координаты, то метод вычисления направления (азимута) будет иным (λ - долгота, φ - широта):

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
```

Comment: Да вот для чего я делал. Всё примерно так https://jsfiddle.net/7f06t6m8/40/

Comment: арккосинус даёт только углы от 0 до 180, т.е. он может дать направление, противоположное реальному. Для того, чтобы увидеть проблему, сделайте несимметричную фигуру, и поместите вторую точку с разных сторон

Answer (score 0):

Арккосинус Х-компоненты вектора AB поделенной на длину этого вектора.

Comment: Это помогло http://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/library/vector/angl/

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS мне помогла моя голова

Comment: Все таки вектор... Жаль, а я ожидал прозрения, которое мне покажет, как точка будет смотреть на другую точку.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko https://jsfiddle.net/7f06t6m8/40/ Хочешь глаззки нарисуй))

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS какие у вас замечательные, изумительные, **квадратные** **точки**, которые имеют размер, и направление взгляда. Просто удивительно, до чего прогресс дошел!